# FoxPro & MYSQL Transaction using Remote View

Tags: mysql, transactions, foxpro

Has anyone used MYSQL Transaction on a FoxPro Remote View?
Can you please share some samples on commit and rollback
scenarios.

These codes doesn't work, record still gets committed even if I issue Rollback.

> lcStringConn = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Port=3306;Server=localhost;Database=testdata;Uid=use;pwd=pass" 
>   =SQLSETPROP(0,"DispLogin",3)
>
> lnHandle=SQLSTRINGCONNECT(lcStringConn)
>
> Open Data testdata
>
> Use table1
>
> =SQLEXEC(lnHandle, 'START TRANSACTION')
>
> Appe Blank
>
> Repl cfield1 with Trans(DateTime())
>
> =SQLExec(lnHandle, 'ROLLBACK')
>
> MyQry="SELECT * from table1" 
>   =SQLEXEC(lnHandle, MyQry ,"MyView", aRows)

Thanks.

EDIT: Im using InnoDB and using SPT, transaction works.

Comment: Are you using Innodb tables? MyISAM tables do not support transactions (the directives are parsed and then ignored).

Comment: Yes am using InnoDB. If I use SQL Pass Through, I am able to roll/revert the changes. Was hoping to use Remote View to lessen my codes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use remote views in Foxpro with an outside datasource such as MYSQL, I would use a database container, such as "testdata" then define a Connection in the database container to your datasource.

Once the Connection has been created, you can use the database container to create your remote views. Just right click in the database container to create your remote view to the table(s) you need in your data source. When defining the view in the remote view designer, make sure to check the "update" check box if you want this view to be update-able.

Then in your code, you can let the VFP database container do the heavy lifting. For example:

```
OPEN DATABASE testdata
USE myRemoteView         &&Assume 1 record retrieve from data source.

REPLACE someField WITH "SomeValue"

IF NOT TableUpdate( 0, .F., "myRemoteView" )
  * The update failed
  TableRevert(.F., "myRemoteView")
ENDIF
```

Give this a try. The other thing you could do is create a stored procedure in MySQL and put the Begin and End Transactions there. Then call these SPs with VFP SQLEXEC().

Comment: I need the transaction for updating two or more Remote Views. If the update on the 1st View fails, I need a way to revert the changes on the 2nd view. 
e.g.

Begin Trans

If TableUpdate(1, .F., 'Table1') and TableUpdate(1, .F., 'Table2')
End Transaction
Else
Rollback
EndIf

This works well on Tables and on Local Views, but if you use this on a remote View, it doesnt work. We need to use MYSQL Transaction for this.

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft SQL if you use Transact SQL BEGIN TRANSACTION the VFP TableUpdate will update the server immediately and you can't do a rollback.  Instead you  have to start the transaction by issuing an implicit manual transaction (DB_TRANSMANUAL) using SQLSetProp:

```
nOldTransactionSetting = SQLGETPROP(_screen.sqlserver.handle,"Transactions")
IF nOldTransactionSetting < 0
    nOldTransactionSetting = 1
ENDIF
=SQLSetprop(_Screen.sqlserver.handle, "TRANSACTIONS", DB_TRANSMANUAL) && start manual transaction       
Begin Transaction       && start VFP transaction
lOkToCont = Tableupdate( 2, .T., 'CursorAdapter1' )
If lOkToCont
    lOkToCont = Tableupdate( 2, .T., 'CursorAdapter2' )
Endif
If lOkToCont        && Commit the transaction on the server and VFP.
    =SQLExec( _Screen.sqlserver.handle, 'IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT' )
    End Transaction
Else                && Rollback the transaction on the server and VFP.
    =SQLExec( _Screen.sqlserver.handle, 'IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK' )
    ROLLBACK
Endif
=SQLSetprop(_Screen.sqlserver.handle, "Transactions", nOldTransactionSetting)
```

I suspect you probably have to do the same thing in MySql.